# Add character to all nodes in phylogenetic tree

Tags: perl, phylogeny

My goal is to add a double underscore ("__") at all nodes (internal and branches) or at least to the internal nodes of a tree in Newick format.

The tree looks like this:

```
(EP00698_Gefionella_okellyi,(EP00699_Malawimonas_sp_californiana,EP00700_Malawimonas_jakobiformis)),((EP00004_Rigifila_ramosa,(EP00001_Collodictyon_triciliatum,EP00002_Diphylleia_rotans)),EP00003_Mantamonas_plastica)
```

I tried to add them with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use Bio::Phylo::IO 'parse';

 my $newick = '(EP00698_Gefionella_okellyi,(EP00699_Malawimonas_sp_californiana,EP00700_Malawimonas_jakobiformis)),((EP00004_Rigifila_ramosa,(EP00001_Collodictyon_triciliatum,EP00002_Diphylleia_rotans)),EP00003_Mantamonas_plastica);';
 my $tree = parse( '-format' => 'newick', '-string' => $newick )->first;

 $tree->visit(
    sub {
        my $node = shift;
        $node->set_name( __ ) if $node->is_internal;
    }
 );

 print $tree->to_newick();;
```

As a result, it gives me the exact same tree, without the modifications that I am trying to get.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `print $tree->to_newick(-nodelabels => 1);` will show labels for internal nodes.

Comment: This solved everything! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should nevertheless add `use strict; use warnings`  to the top of your program then fix the error (quoting `'__'`). Strict and warnings will save you lots of headaches on the long run.